# error with QML/ C++ compilation

Tags: c++, qml

We used our C++ classes (headers and sources) as plugins in our QML project (using QtCreator as our IDE).

We keep getting this error:

```
erreur : undefined reference to `_imp___ZN16QDeclarativeItemC2ERKS_'
```

How can we fix this?

Comment: *.PRO file: `QT += declarative`

Answer (score 1):

You need to link Qt's declarative library.  See [the documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtdeclarative.html#details) for details.

Comment: Oh of course we already did that !! so there must be another reason for that error , we looked online but nothing , thanks for trying , we appreciate it .